# using cProfile to profile a code with decorators have strange results

Tags: python, profiling, decorator, cprofile, snakeviz

So i'm using cProfile and snakeviz to profil my code. My code has decorator which seems to make the cProfile results not very correct :

my code :

```
import time
import decorator


@decorator.decorator
def my_deco(f, *args, **kwargs):
    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return ret

def a():
    time.sleep(2)
    b()
    c()

@my_deco
def b():
    time.sleep(3)
    d()

@my_deco
def c():
    time.sleep(1)
    d()
    
@my_deco
def d():
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a()
```

profiling without decorator (expected behavior) :
In this case, b, c are at the same level and d bellow.

[image]

profiling with decorator (not wanted behavior) :
In this case, b, c and d are at the same level.

[image]